# Jquery delete row with ajax call

Tags: jquery

I have the following function that deletes an entire row:

```
$(".deleteTR").click(function(e){

    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this entry?")) {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    }

    return false;
})
```

I want to go to the controller where the delete function is placed, I tried to use this ajax call but it is not working and it doesn't go to the controller:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: '@Url.Action("Delete", "Application")',
  data: JSON.stringify(app),
  dataType: "json",
  contentType: "application/json",
  cache: false,
  success: function(data) {
    //show content
    alert('success')
  },
});
```

The controller method:

```
//Post
    [HttpPost, ActionName("DeletePack")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeletePackageConfirmed (int id)
    {
        Package package = db.Packages.Find(id);

        db.Packages.Remove(package);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Comment: Where this code is placed? in a separate `js` file? Check for any console errors..

Comment: I mean, is this in a `js` file or `.cshtml` file??

Comment: Can you show your Controller method? Are there any browser console errors?

Comment: yes,  http://localhost/DeploymentApp/Application/DeletePack 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: btw I edited the code and added the controller method

Comment: You have internal server error.. Did you place a debugger in VS and checked where it is erroring out in controller method?

Comment: Thanks for this info I tried another solution and it's working now

Comment: You can post it as answer so that it will help others..

Comment: I tried another way and changed the whole function

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this code :

```
      $(".deleteTR").click(function(e) {

        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this entry?")) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("Delete", "Application")',
            data:  JSON.stringify( app),
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                $(this).closest('tr').remove();
                alert ('success')
            },

        });

        }

        return false;
    })
```

Comment: Same thing, it doesn't go to the controller